# How can change pixmap and move it alternatively in pyqt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

**raiseTemmie.py**

```
import random
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QApplication

class Example(QWidget):
    size=100
    imgNum=0
    imgQuantity=2

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.label=QLabel(self)
        self.pixmaps=[QPixmap('left.png'),QPixmap('right.png'),QPixmap('stand.png')]
        for x in range(len(self.pixmaps)):
            self.pixmaps[x]=self.pixmaps[x].scaled(self.size,self.size,Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmaps[2])
        self.resize(self.pixmaps[2].width(),self.pixmaps[2].height())
        self.show()

    def moving(self):
        distance=random.randint(10,40)
        direct =[random.randint(-1,2),random.randint(-1,2)]
        for x in range(0,distance):
            self.changeFoot()
            self.move(self.x()+5*direct[0],self.y()+5*direct[1])
            time.sleep(0.05)
        # self.changeTimer.stop()


    def changeFoot(self):
        if self.imgNum<self.imgQuantity-1:
            self.imgNum+=1
        else :
            self.imgNum=0
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmaps[self.imgNum])

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmaps[2])
        self.changeTimer.stop()

    changeTimer=QTimer()
    def keyPressEvent(self, QKeyEvent):
        if QKeyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            sys.exit()
        if QKeyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_G:
            self.moving()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I thought this code would switch the pixmap and move it simultaneously but it do not work well.
The timer start after moving finished. What is the problem?

```
def keyPressEvent(self, QKeyEvent):
    if QKeyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
        sys.exit()
    if QKeyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_G:
        self.moving()
```

if I press 'G', it starts the changeTimer and calls moving()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `qApp.processEvents()` to update the data, this is recommended when tasks require little time as is your case, since the maximum time of the loop is `0.05sec*40=2sec`.

```
def moving(self):
    distance=random.randint(10,40)
    direct =[random.randint(-1,2),random.randint(-1,2)]
    for x in range(0,distance):
        self.changeFoot()
        self.move(self.x()+5*direct[0],self.y()+5*direct[1])
        time.sleep(0.05)
        qApp.processEvents()
```

The solution may fail if time grows, another solution is to implement the timer and separate the tasks correctly as I show below:

```
class Example(QWidget):
    size=100
    imgNum=0
    imgQuantity=2

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.label=QLabel(self)
        self.pixmaps=[QPixmap('left.png'),QPixmap('right.png'),QPixmap('stand.png')]
        for x in range(len(self.pixmaps)):
            self.pixmaps[x]=self.pixmaps[x].scaled(self.size,self.size,Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmaps[2])
        self.resize(self.pixmaps[2].width(),self.pixmaps[2].height())

        self.changeTimer=QTimer(self)
        self.changeTimer.timeout.connect(self.onTimeout)
        self.show()

    def moving(self):
        self.distance= random.randint(10,40)
        self.direct = QPoint(random.randint(-1,2), random.randint(-1,2))
        self.changeTimer.start(50)

    def onTimeout(self):
        if self.distance == 0:
            self.changeTimer.stop()
        else:
            self.changeFoot()
            self.move(self.pos() +  self.direct)
        self.distance -= 1   

    def changeFoot(self):
        if self.imgNum<self.imgQuantity-1:
            self.imgNum+=1
        else :
            self.imgNum=0
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmaps[self.imgNum])

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmaps[2])
        self.changeTimer.stop()

    def keyPressEvent(self, QKeyEvent):
        if QKeyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
        if QKeyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_G:
            self.moving()
```

*Note: It is advisable to use `self.close()` instead of `sys.exit()` since the first gives time for the program to free resources and close properly.*